# How Do I Signal Browser To Make a Call Through Five9?

Tags: crm, phone-call, five9

I'm making a custom CRM and need a dialer button or link to place a call. I want to have a button on a phone number where I can click it and Five9 will automatically call it over its SIP service. If I have installed the Five9 Desktop Toolkit, does it automatically make every tel: link open via Five9, or do I have to make a hyperlink a certain way in order for Five9 to start the call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique is to install on the call taker's PC the Five9 Desktop Toolkit and browser plugin. This permits the browser access to a Javascript API to interface with a web server on the call taker's PC on an alternative port. This web service is an XML SOAP service called CTI. The following example shows how to use CTI to place a call through the Five9 dialer:

https://github.com/Five9DeveloperProgram/Five9CTISample

This is another example that is more direct:

https://github.com/Five9DeveloperProgram/Five9Click2DialSample